# How to run a package's testthat tests

Tags: r, testthat

For a given installed package, how do I run its testthat tests?  I'm not a developer of the installed package, I'm a user. I just want to run its test suite to confirm its tests pass in my environment.  I've tried `test_check` and `test_package` but I see errors.

To be more specific,  I know its test suite fails and I want to run the tests in an interactive R session so I can debug it.

```
> require(eplusr)    # choice of package unimportant. Any using testthat will do.
Loading required package: eplusr
> require(testthat)
Loading required package: testthat
> test_check("eplusr")
Error in test_files(paths, reporter = reporter, env = env, stop_on_failure = stop_on_failure,  : 
  No matching test file in dir
> test_package("eplusr")
Error: No tests found for eplusr


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8      
 [8] LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] testthat_2.0.0 eplusr_0.9.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18      magrittr_1.5      units_0.6-0       hms_0.4.2         progress_1.2.0    uuid_0.1-2        bit_1.1-14        debugme_1.1.0     R6_2.2.2          rlang_0.2.2      
[11] stringr_1.3.1     blob_1.1.1        tools_3.5.1       data.table_1.11.5 cli_1.0.0         DBI_1.0.0         withr_2.1.2       bit64_0.9-7       assertthat_0.2.0  digest_0.6.16    
[21] tibble_1.4.2      crayon_1.3.4      processx_3.2.0    readr_1.1.1       callr_3.0.0       later_0.7.4       base64enc_0.1-3   ps_1.1.0          fasttime_1.0-2    memoise_1.1.0    
[31] RSQLite_2.1.1     stringi_1.2.4     pillar_1.3.0      compiler_3.5.1    prettyunits_1.0.2 lubridate_1.7.4   pkgconfig_2.0.2
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

R doesn't install the testthat tests by default.  To do so try :

```
install.packages('eplusr', INSTALL_opts="--install-tests", type='source')
```

Then, either:

```
testthat::test_package('eplusr')
```

or alternatively using the built-in `testInstalledPackage`:

```
tools::testInstalledPackage('eplusr')
```

Answer (score 12):

You can't (unless you reinstall overriding default behaviour as shown in Brodie's answer).

It's a design flaw^Hchoice.  `testthat`, in all its wisdom, decided to *not* install tests by default by enforcing the placement in the `tests/` directory.  R offers an option to override it (as shown) which is generally not turned on. Hence the dilemma.

Of course, `RUnit` did it correctly all along having tests below `inst/`.  So if a package uses `RUnit` you can run its tests once installed. Without having to reinstall it.

*Edit:* 1 1/2 years later, many of us now use the [tinytest](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=tinytest) package which arrived within the last year. Among other advantages, also allows *very easy* testing of installed packages.