# Exclude large test files from package in R

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I have developed an R package where I need to use a large dataset for testing. However, I don't want to bundle this dataset with the package (as doing so increases the package size from a few hundred KB to a few hundred MB).

One option is to add this file to `.Rbuildignore`. However, whilst this allows my tests to pass with `devtools::test()`, they then fail with `devtools::check()`. Removing this file from `.Rbuildignore` allows `devtools::check()` to pass, but increases the package size.

Is there any way to make this file findable by `devtools::check()` whilst not bundling it with the package?

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this? Seems to me there are two possible cases here: 1. This is a package for your own personal use, in which case you don't need to pass `devtools::check()`.  2. You intend to share this package, in which case `devtools::check()` is telling you something important, i.e. others cannot run the tests.

Comment: I intend to release this package. Perhaps this is showing my naivety in terms of R package development (this is my first one), but I was thinking that it was irrelevant whether others could run the tests in an automated way. Does this happen during installation? I had planned to add a link to this large test dataset in the README so that if users wanted to run all tests then then could, but otherwise they would not need to download it.

Comment: Tests aren't usually run during install - whether R even installs tests with the package [depends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175265/how-to-run-a-packages-testthat-tests). But if you're publishing source code which includes tests, they should be runnable. Do your tests need that much data - what are you testing? The [test directory](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/tree/master/inst/tests) for `data.table` is 1.29mb, though it contains a lot of compressed data (`.gz`). If you do need the data to be very large, could you generate test data with some code?

Comment: Ok, thank you - I will try to slim down some of the test data (or generate it procedurally). I will leave this question open here though since I am still curious about whether my proposal is technically possible.